# how to use NDk with android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, react-native

I try to convert `com.android.model.application` to `com.android.application`

How can I do that? The problem is with `CFlags.add`.

This my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.0'
    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId "com.update.myapp"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
    }
}
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "Test_Jni"
    CFlags.add("-DCOMPANION_DEVICE")
    CFlags.add("-DDISABLE_LOGS")
    CFlags.addAll(["-I${file("src/main/jni/Folder1/")}".toString(),
                   "-I${file("src/main/jni/Folder2")}".toString(),

            "-I${file("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyFile\\folder1_Cfiles/")}".toString(),
             "-I${file("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyFile\\folder2_Cfiles/")}".toString()])
    ldLibs.addAll(["log"])
}
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs "src/main/jni"
                srcDirs "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyFile\\folder1_Cfiles"
                srcDirs "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyFile\\folder2_Cfiles"
            }
        }
    }
}dependencies{  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'}
```

Comment: When switching to **com.android.application**, you must provide your **Android.mk** or **CMakeLists.txt**. These files use GNU Make or CMake scripting languages, respectively, and you will set all compilation flags etc. in that script.

Comment: Hi @AlexCohn 
this my Android.mk but i still have problem can you check it
LOCAL_PATH :=$(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Test_Jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Test_Jni.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=\ $(LOCAL_PATH)/ jni \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/Folder1 \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/Folder2 \
 $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../../../../../Program Files (x86)\\MyFile\\folder1_Cfiles\
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../../../../../Program Files (x86)\\MyFile\\folder2_Cfiles \
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: No, please don't use comments for multi-line text

Comment: One big NO: don't use paths that have space when you work with NDK!

Comment: Second big NO: don't use such long relative paths for LOCAL_C_INCLUDES. It's OK to use absolute paths if you need.